# How to use calculus to solve the equation: $(x^3-4)^3=\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+4)^2}+4\right)^2$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I've recently started learning calculus. Someone told me that some equations can be solved using derivatives. I was  interested about that and I wanted to learn how to do that. As an example problem, I tried to solve an equation using derivatives. Here is the equation:

> **Problem:** Solve for $x \in \mathbb R$: $$(x^3-4)^3=\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+4)^2}+4\right)^2.$$

(The problem is taken from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191706/solving-x3-43-sqrt3x24242), which was posted a few days ago. I answered the question with an algebraic solution and now I want to know about the solution which uses calculus.)
Here is my solution to the problem. I want to know whether my solution is correct or not and I also have some questions regarding the solution.

**My solution:**
It is easy to see that $x\geq \sqrt[3]4$ for equality. And we notice that $x=2$ is a solution.
Let $f(x)=(x^3-4)^3$ and $g(x)=\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+4)^2}+4\right)^2$ defined on $[\sqrt[3]4,+\infty)$. Then, $f'(x)=9x^2(x^3-4)^2$ and $$g'(x)=\frac{8x}{3}(\sqrt[3]{x^2+4})+\frac{8x}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2+4}}.$$ Clearly, $f'(x)>g'(x)$ in the interval.
The graph of $f$ is more increasing than $g$ after the equality. So, $f$ and $g$ is can't hold equality for $x>2$, which implies $x=2$ is the only solution to the equation.

The solution says there is no equality for $x>2$. But how to know there is no equality points in $[\sqrt[3]4,2)$? I need an explanation for that. (It would be easy for me if the answer is in terms of graphs of the functions as I don't know much calculus.)
And is this kind of solution to an equation suitable for contests i.e. olympiads (I want to know this because I participate in various contests.)?

**Note:** The above solution has some errors. I need to prove that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can't be equal except $x=2$. My workings are not correct as figured out in comments.

Comment: I would say you need to justify more why $f' > g'$. I imagine this is acceptable in contests, but to make sure I would suggest for you to contact the organizers.

Comment: Assuming it is true that $f’(x)-g’(x)>0$ so $f-g$ is strictly increasing and thus can have only one zero.

Comment: But your computation for $f’(x)$ is obviously wrong, since $f’(x)$ must be $3x^2\cdot 3(x^3-4)^2$, so must be divisible by $x^2$ and all the terms must be divisible by $9.$

Comment: Also, $f’(\sqrt[3]4)=0<g’(\sqrt[3]4),$ so the inequality can’t be right on the whole interval. It might be true for $x\geq2,$ which is enough to see there is no solution $>2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As $f(x)=x^9-12x^2+48x-64$, $f'(x)=9x^8-24x+48$ (sorry if I am missing something). And I assumed $f'(x)>g'(x)$ because it seemed true to me as $f'(x)$ is an eighth degree polynomial and $g'(x)$ involves cube roots.

Comment: $$f(x)=x^9-12x^6+48x^3-64.$$ You forgot that the term is $x^3$ in the later terms. @Unknown But the chain rule was enough for me to figure you were wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've just edited this issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You haven't clarified which interval $f'>g'.$ It is not all of $(\sqrt[3]4,\infty).$ @Unknown

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is also not clear to me. How do we prove that $f$ and $g$ can't be equal for $x> 2$? I need help.

Comment: If $f'>g'$ for $x\geq 2,$ this means $h=f-g$ is increasing, so $h(x)>h(2)=0$ for $x>2.$ But that assumes we've shown $f'>g'$ for $x>2.$ So far, we've merely asserted that. @Unknown

Comment: @Unknown Contest problems can be one-trick ponies and I don't think this one was "designed" to be solved this way. $\,f-g\,$ is not  increasing on $\,[\sqrt[3]{4}, 2)\,$, in fact $\,f'-g'\,$ [has a $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+%28x%5E3-4%29%5E3+-+%28cbrt%28%28x%5E2%2B4%29%5E2%29%2B4%29%5E2+%29%27+%3D+0) in that interval. And proving it by brute force leads to an algebraic equation of [degree $27$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%5E3-4%29%5E3-16%29%5E3+-+%28x%5E2%2B4%29%5E4+-+8%28x%5E2%2B4%29%5E2%283%28x%5E3-4%29%5E3%2B16%29+%3D+0), doable by CAS but not by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Taking instead

$$
x^3 = 4 + ((x^2 + 4)^{\frac 23} + 4)^{\frac 23} = f(x)
$$

$f(x)$ has the properties:

$$
\cases{
f(x) = \mathcal{O}\left(|x|^{\frac 89}\right)\\
f'(x) = \frac{x}{g(x)},\  \ \ g(x)\gt 0\\
f(x) \ge 4+\left(4+2 \sqrt[3]{2}\right)^{2/3}
}
$$

so $x^3$ and $f(x)$ only intersect at one point. As $x=2$ is a solution, this occurs at the intersection point.